# Installing GCC in Solaris_x86

Tags: solaris, gcc

I have tried Googling for my answer, but everyone is saying GCC is already installed on the Solaris Operating System. They said to add `/usr/sfw/bin` to your `$PATH`, which I did, and rebooted the machine, but still nothing happened, when I tried compiling my software using GCC.

But when I do the following find command as the root user:

```
find / -name gcc
```

I get no results returned. That to me indicates there is no GCC installed on this system.

Where can I get it from and install it on the system?

***Note:** This is not on SPARC but on VMWare.*

Comment: type gcc on command line & plz paste the output here....

Comment: SPARC or x86 makes no difference. There is no need to reboot after modifying the PATH environment variable. What Solaris version is it (`cat /etc/release`) and who installed it ?

Comment: @raghavmishra so I just type gcc? i.e. it will look like this: `$ gcc`? - OK, I did that and it says: `-bash: gcc: command not found`

Comment: @jlliagre it is `Oracle Solaris 11.1 X86` and I installed it.

Comment: @raghavmishra: After installing GCC using `pkg install gcc-45`, I typed gcc in the command line, and it now shows `gcc: no input files` - thank you guys :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little more research, I have found that I can use

```
pkg install gcc-45
```

and now that is busy downloading. I was weary of using that, as in the other Linux machines, you can't use `pkg`.

Thanks for looking and trying to help me solve this, but I think it is sorted now.

Comment: It is unclear if you are aware of this or not but in any case, Solaris is not a Linux distribution so has its own way(s) to install packages (just like you won't do it the same way on say Ubuntu, Red Hat or Slackware).

Comment: Oh ok, no I didn't know that. Thank you. I am still very new at UNIX. :-)

Comment: OK, what happens is just that the package wasn't installed. Find out how to check what packages are installed, and what is available (I've not used Solaris in more than 10 years, so I'm no help there). Consider carefully what else you might need.

Answer (score 2):

The advice you got about where to find `gcc` relates to Solaris 10, not Solaris 11. You have already learned that for Solaris 11 you need to install a package called `gcc-45` but that isn't enough.

Here's the list GNU packages that I believe should exist on any Solaris system:

Just execute as follows:

```
pkg install pkg://solaris/archiver/gnu-tar
pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/gnu-binutils
pkg install pkg://solaris/diagnostic/top
pkg install pkg://solaris/file/gnu-coreutils
pkg install pkg://solaris/file/gnu-findutils
pkg install pkg://solaris/text/gawk
pkg install pkg://solaris/text/gnu-diffutils
pkg install pkg://solaris/text/gnu-grep
pkg install pkg://solaris/text/gnu-sed
```

(no, I understand you didn't really ask for this but having them available will make your life easier down the road)

Here's what you asked for: If you use the host for development/build purpose you should add:

```
pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/build/gnu-make
pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/build/make
pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/gcc-45
pkg install pkg://solaris/system/header
pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/build/autoconf
pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/build/automake-110
```

(just installing `gcc-45` isn't enough)

The above will give you a host with all the traditional GNU/Linux tools and the traditional tools for C/C++ development that are typically used by various open source packages during the build/compile process.

The GNU tools take up very, very little disk space so really no reason not to install them IMHO. The dev tools take up a bit more so you can leave them out on hosts where you don't want to do build/compile.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I got it to work with just that `gcc-45`, all I need is that compiler.

Comment: ok, then you are in luck. I needed at least the headers (`system/header`)